# error: redefinition of 'struct timespec'

Tags: c, networking, struct

**myheader.h**

```
#ifndef _MYHEAD_
#define _MYHEAD_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

#endif
```

**echoClient.c**

```
#include "myheader.h"

int clock_gettime(clockid_t clock_id, struct timespec *tp);
int nanosleep(const struct timespec *req, struct timespec *rem);

typedef struct timespec // error message line
{
    time_t tv_sec;
    long tv_nsec;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int s;
    char* servName;
    int servPort;
    char* string;
    char buf[256 + 1];
    int len = 0;
    int maxLen = sizeof(buf);
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    timespec t1,t2,t3;
    double practice;
    int temp = 0;
    int n;



    if(argc != 4)
    {
            printf("Usage: client <server> <port> <virtual packet size> <string>\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    servName = argv[1];
    servPort = atoi(argv[2]);

    string = argv[3];

    memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

    /* Create remote (server) socket address */
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, servName, &serverAddr.sin_addr);     // server IP addr
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);

    practice = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&t3);
    printf("time %f\n",practice);

    /* Creat socket */
    if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
            perror("Error: socket creation failed\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    // send the echo message
    n = sendto(s, string, strlen(string), 0,
            (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    printf("-- actual tx frame size:  (%d bytes)\n",n);

    /* here, the message has been sent, and the echo will come */

    /* receive Echo */
    memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    len = recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, NULL, NULL);
    buf[len] = '\0';

    printf("Echoed string received: ");
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    close(s);
    exit(0);
}
```

As you can see the topic,

> "error:redefinition of 'struct timespec'

have been happened when i try to compile.

> /usr/include/time.h:122: error: previous definition of 'struct timespec'

have been also happened. How can i modify this code.

Please help me.

Comment: The compiler tells you the answer.

Comment: Show the exact compilation command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timespec` is defined in the following way into `time.h`

```
struct timespec
  {
    __time_t tv_sec;        /* Seconds.  */
    __syscall_slong_t tv_nsec;  /* Nanoseconds.  */
  };
```

Remove the struct definition in your code.

Prototype at the top of your code must be removed, also

```
int clock_gettime(clockid_t clock_id, struct timespec *tp);
int nanosleep(const struct timespec *req, struct timespec *rem);
```

Are already defined in time.h

Last thing, definition of 
`timespec t1,t2,t3;`
Must be
`struct timespec t1,t2,t3;`

**EDIT**

If you add `-Wall` option compiler gives you warning about unused variable: `temp`, `maxlen`, `t1` and `t2`

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply. According to your suggestion, i try to remove the struct lines. However, i met the compile error like this.. "echoClient.c:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `clock_gettime' "

Answer (score 1):

`struct timespec` is defined in `time.h`. Don't define your own again.

You should remove the `typedef struct timespec { ... };` part in `echoClient.c`.

Comment: According to your suggestion, i try to remove the struct lines. However, i met the compile error like this.. "echoClient.c:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `clock_gettime' "

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in Ecliepse Neon IDE and i resolved it by adding '-DHAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC' in C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous -> Others flag

https://github.com/ghostlander/nsgminer/issues/1